# call time reference issue with php

Tags: php, reference

```
function get_arr($arr)
{
    unset($arr[0]);
}
$arr1 = array(1,2);
$arr2 = array(1,2);

get_arr(&$arr1);
get_arr($arr2);
echo count($arr1);
echo count($arr2);
```

I got :

> Warning: Call-time pass-by-reference
>   has been deprecated; If you would like
>   to pass it by reference,  modify the
>   declaration of get_arr().  If you
>   would like to enable call-time
>   pass-by-reference, you can set
>   allow_call_time_pass_reference to true
>   in your INI file

But the output is:

```
12
```

Which means the call time reference takes effect.

Why the two places output contradictary messages?

Comment: I think get_arr(&$arr1); provide your function not array but string "1";

Comment: @ARTstudio: What makes you think that? `get_arr(&$arr1)` passes `$arr1` (an array) *by reference* to `get_arr()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deprecated does not mean non-functional, it's just not recommended.

Comment: Not recommended and also they will be removing that functionality in later versions of PHP. So get ready for a lot of code to break when they do.

Comment: @Clutch: of course before upgrading to a new version of PHP you should always check the incompatible changes

Answer (score 1):

Call-time pass-by-reference is *deprecated*, that means it should not be used any more and may not be working in a future version of PHP. It does not mean that it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

It's a warning.

It is just warning you, but at the same time trusts that you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

the source of confusion is that error message is vague, it should read "to get rid of this warning, set allow_call_time_pass_reference to true" instead of "to enable call-time pass-by-reference".